# How to customize or debug ad-blocking on gnome-web (epiphany-browser)?

Tags: gnome, epiphany

Gnome-web (new name for epiphany browser) have a ad-blocking feature, which is by default activated.

But sometimes, I get the impression that elements that are not ads are blocked (false positives), that some ads from a particular country are not blocked. Also, after installing gnome-3.12 from ppa gnome-team/staging, ad-blocking completely stopped working.

What is the principle of the filter implemented in gnome-web ? How can I troubleshoot/debug ad-blocking ? Can I configure the blocking patterns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 3.24, [`filters.list` has been removed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/epiphany/commit/3a5bfb106fc136ef087f91c08e573350932a1cf3), and some time in or around 3.32 it was [replaced with a list in `gsettings`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/epiphany/issues/268). You can either edit the list graphically using `dconf-editor`, under `/org/gnome/epiphany/adblock-filters`, or via the command-line:

```sh
$ gsettings get org.gnome.Epiphany adblock-filters
['https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt', 'https://easylist.to/easylist/easyprivacy.txt']
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Epiphany adblock-filters "['https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt', 'https://easylist.to/easylist/easyprivacy.txt', 'https://additional.filter.list/]"
```

### Pre-3.24 instructions:

[GNOME Web](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Web%20Gnome-web) blocks ads on the basis of the URI of the element. The blocking is done by the UriTester componant ([source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/epiphany/tree/embed/uri-tester.c)). Like Adblock plus, the tester loads a list of patterns from a list, and determine if a URI is an ad if it matches one of the pattern.

The file `$HOME_DIR/.config/epiphany/adblock/filters.list` contains the locations of the lists to load (one on each line, with a `;` at the end of line). If this file doesn't exists (e.g. first time you run epiphany), it defaults to "https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt". Gnome-web then download (and periodically refresh) the pattern lists, and store them in the same directory (with file name like `bedc7ed868397c3dcaf6bc40ed9bbf70`)

So, in case of troubles, check that you have filters.list, with one line pointing to a valid adblock+ filter, and one file with a file name of 32 hex chars, containing valid blocking pattern. If the file `filters.list` exists, *but is empty*, ads won't be filtered at all.

It is also possible to customize the list used by changing the url in filter.list (for instance replacing the default list with a localised list like `https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/liste_fr+easylist.txt`).

Comment: Please also note that some InternetProviders now block the URL https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt from their DNS to prevent the user of using Adblock. You can use custom DNS to prevent that if you can't download the list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this works anymore with the latest GNOME Web. I don't want to block ads, as that's how my favorite website make money, what I don't want is being tracked across the web. I like to use EasyPrivacy, but I noticed adding that string to GNOME Web via Dconf editor it is just ignored.